# Rails: Same "Create" action conditional between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, controller

Making a site in with three main models: Users, Posts, and Gyms. Users should be able to post either from their own model (User.post), or, if they are the admin of a gym, from the Gym's model (Gym.post).

I'm using the same post controller and post form to post fro either the gym or the user, but the controller "Create" action can't distinguish between the two.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,  only: :destroy

  def create
    if (gym.gym_admin == current_user.id)
      @post = gym.posts.build(post_params)
       if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Post!"
        redirect_to "/gyms/#{gym.id}"
       else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
       end
     else  
      @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
      if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Post!"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Post deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

   private

   def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:post_type, :title, :content, :picture,     :body_parts,
                              :duration, :equipment, :calories, :protein,
                              :fat, :carbs, :ingredients, :tag_list,
                              :postable_id, :postable_type)
   end

   def correct_user
     @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:postable_id])
     redirect_to root_url if @post.nil?
   end

   def gym
     @gym = Gym.find_by(params[:id])
   end

end
```

And the Models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gym 
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true

class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :posts, as: :postable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :gyms

class Gym < ApplicationRecord

has_many :posts, as: :postable, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
```

Rught now, this create action only creates posts from the gym's model; if I remove the first half of the conditional, it will only post from the User model.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: it may seem more repetitive but it'll probably be simpler if you use two different controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it my removing the conditional logic altogether; I just made two separate custom actions in the controller and called them from different links. ie. :actions => create_gym / create_user

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious what `gym.gym_admin` (and consequently the whole line below 'def create') evaluates to since I don't see in referenced anywhere else.

My suspicion is that you would want to change

```
if (gym.gym_admin == current_user.id)
```

to

```
if (gym.gym_admin.id == current_user.id)
```

or

```
if (gym.gym_admin == current_user)
```

once that relationship is working correctly.

Also, could post be built independently of whether a user is a gym admin and send the post params the gym_id if applicable. Then accessed either through:

```
/gym/:id
@posts = Post.where('gym_id = ?', params[:id])
```

or

```
/user/:id
@posts = Post.where('user_id = ?', params[:id])
```

Comment: the gym.gym_admin value is a hidden_tag in the gym#new form that generates and integer from the current_user.id.  `<%= f.hidden_field :gym_admin, :value => current_user.id %>`    I've now separated the "create" action into to actions in the PostsController: `def create_gym_post` and `def create_user_post` and now I think that I should be able to find a way to route the post params through one or the other of these        >`post 'posts', to: 'posts#create_gym_post' `   
  >`post 'posts', to: 'posts#create_user_post'`  but I ant seem how to do it...

Comment: In that case could you could conditionally change the method / display a different form based on whether the person was an admin?